# Mysql search with semi colon delimited string

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables that look like this

```
table A            table B
id | data          id  | features
---------          --------------
1  | blue          1A  | 1;2
2  | red           2B  | 1;2;3 
3  | yellow        3B  | 3;1
......             ......
```

**What i plan to do** is something like this, where i query one table. loop thru the array of results and explode the data with the semicolon delimiter. then loop thru that new array and query it to get the data (note code below not tested)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tableB` WHERE `id`= '2B' LIMIT 1";

$query = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

       $arr = explode(';', $row['features']); 

       for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++)
       {
               $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE `id`="'.$arr[$i].'"";
               $query2 = $db->query($sql2);
               while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
                     $r[] = $row2['data'];
              }
       }
}

print_r($r);
```

is there a way i can achieve this just in mysql, where i match the column in tableB with the ID's in tableA? or maybe by not using a nested loop? performance is key. coz both tables have more than 25k rows of data.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think a better way is to restructure your table. Normalize it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code. Reduced few loops.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tableB` WHERE `id`= '2B' LIMIT 1";
$query = $db->query($sql);
$arr = explode(';', $row['features']); 

$str = implode(",", $arr);

$sql2 = "SELECT  * FROM `tableA WHERE id IN ({$str});";

$query2 = $db->query($sql2);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $r[] = $row2['data'];
}
```

Comment: getting an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A76,A70,A07,A08,A15})` the query looks like this `SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE `id` IN ({A76,A70,A07,A08,A15})`

Comment: then i remove the `{}` i get `Unknown column 'A76' in 'where clause'`

Comment: had to add "" around all my ID's for it to work here is the code `$str = "'" . implode("','", $arr) . "'";`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [IN function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

This will take an array of id's and give you every result in a single query.

So your code should look like this after you apply it

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $new_query = str_replace(";", ",", $row['features']); 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE `id` IN ($new_query)";
    $query2 = $db->query($sql2);
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $r[] = $row2['data'];
    }
}
```

Comment: getting an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A76,A70,A07,A08,A15})` the query looks like this `SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE `id` IN ({A76,A70,A07,A08,A15})`

Comment: I edited the code. I was using the query variable instead of new_query. It should work now.

Comment: hmm, your $sql2 is still the same tho. my query generated is `SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE `id` IN (A76,A70,A07,A08,A15)`